# NVD3 chart partly missing grid lines

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

In [my chart here](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/vfe2B/7/embedded/result/), if you can notice, it is missing grid lines for the first 4 and last 4 dates.

I tried doing:

```
.ticks(data[0].length)
```

but it didnt help.

What am I missing?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/vfe2B/7/embedded/result/)

Comment: The problem is with the width of the chart. When the chart resizes it automatically adjust the `tick`. NVD3 multiBarChart has a method called `reduceXTicks` to handle that, unfotunately not with lineChart.

Comment: @shabeer90 Thanks! If I increase the width to `4800px`, I can see the complete grid. Is there any hack around this so that the full grid is shown at any width?

Comment: Your code currently has `nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);` which automatically resizes the the chart according to the window. Try without that line.

Comment: @shabeer90 That didnt change anything. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding .showMaxMin(false) fixes the problem.

```
      chart.xAxis
       .showMaxMin(false)
       .axisLabel("My X-Axis")
       .tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d)) });
```

Working example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3mhB2/embedded/result/)

Comment: Thanks! Any idea about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24544859/how-to-update-nvd3-line-chart-with-additional-series

Comment: Maybe these links will be helpful: 
[NVD3 line chart with realtime data](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12548640/2697673)
[Real time line graph with nvd3.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330390/real-time-line-graph-with-nvd3-js)
[Update existing chart with new data](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/26)

Comment: I would like to have MaxMin as well as gridlines at the end. Any ideas?