# X-axis label misplaced

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

In [my NVD3 chart here](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/vfe2B/28), I rotated and translated the X-axis `ticks`. As a result, the X-axis label `My X-axis` got affected too.

JS:

```
    var xTicks = d3.select('.nv-x.nv-axis > g').selectAll('g');

    xTicks
      .selectAll('text')
      .attr('transform', function(d,i,j) { 
          return 'translate (-10, 40) rotate(-90 0,0)';
       )}
```

How do I modify this code to skip formatting the X-axis label?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/vfe2B/28)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had selected all the `text` elements earlier to be transformed. Select only the `tick` labels.

Try the below

```
xTicks.selectAll('g > .tick > text').attr('transform', function(d, i, j) {
    return 'translate (-10, 40) rotate(-90 0,0)'
});

// Bring the 'My X-Axis' label down to avoid overlap.
xTicks.select('.nv-axislabel').attr("y", 90)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: That worked like a charm! But now the problem is that the X-axis label is getting behind the ticks: http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/vfe2B/29/ How do I move it downward?

Comment: Ah, missed that! Could you help me with this followup question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523744/nvd3-chart-partly-missing-grid-lines